# Update App to add redirect url

Tags: url, redirect, edit, soundcloud

I registered my app, but didn't provide a redirect url. Now my app has been approved, but I have no way to edit so I can add it.

Please let me know how I can add my redirect url to the sound cloud api settings for my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

best way is to edit the code and deploy new package it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get in touch with SoundCloud Support to do this: support@soundcloud.com.